# SELinux enforcing mode problem

Tags: boot, selinux

I install selinux-basics and selinux-policy-default in ubuntu server 13.04, but when i set selinux in enforcing mode and reboot, my system doesn't boot up and I get following error:

```
mountall: mount /run/lock [424] terminated with status 32
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /run/lock
mountall: mount /run/shm [426] terminated with status 32
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /run/shm
mountall: mount /run/usr [427] terminated with status 32
mountall: Filesystem could not be mounted: /run/usr

An error occured while mounting /run/lock
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click your ubuntu-*.iso > Open with Disk Image writer
2. Choose your usb drive and click Start Restoring... and follow the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press shift on boot up
2. Select advanced options
3. Select the latest image with a "(recovery mode) " then select "root" put this command: setenforce=0 then put exit then resume without rebooting then login go to /etc/selinux but, open terminal first then navigate to etc then chmod a+rwx selinux then edit conf file then disable it then press save and reboot. Voila it's solved!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ronald, but the question is thee years old and refers to an end-of-life release (even then).